# Subquery in snowflake with unknown matches, matches to columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, subquery

I have a few tables that I'm joining and one of them can have an unknown number of matches, up to 6.  Each match should be returned as a row value in the initial query.  For example:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.match1, a.match2, a.match3, a.match4, a.match5, a.match6
FROM table1 a, (SELECT ID, match FROM table2 WHERE a.ID = table2.ID) b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID
```

That's probably not the right syntax but hopefully it shows what I need.  So the nested query MAY return 1 match or 5.  Each match should be the value for the corresponding column name, ie a.match1 = first match, b.match2 = second match, etc etc.

Please let me know if I need to explain further.  I know this isn't the optimal schema to use but it's what I was told to work with.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result based on that data

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I would (a) look into just using a straight JOIN from table1 to table2, which would give you a record for each match, and then PIVOT that recordset into columns.  Is that what you are looking for?  If so, take a look at the PIVOT function in Snowflake documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html

Comment: I will look in to that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something that SQL doesn't like is an unknown number of columns.

As a quick hack, you could aggregate all matches in an array, and then have a query around it transforming the matches into a predefined (large) number of columns.

Like this:

```sql
with data as (
select $1 id
from (values(1),(2))
), data2 as (
select $1 id, $2 match
from (values(1, 'a1'),(1, 'a2'),(2, 'b1'),(2, 'b2'),(2, 'b3'))
)

select id, matches[0], matches[1], matches[2], matches[3]
from (
    select a.id, array_agg(match) matches
    from data a
    join data2 b
    on a.id=b.id
    group by 1
);
```

[image]